# AJAX SyntaxError: Invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The logic flow I'm trying to achieve is as following:

Select filters from popup => Generate the main view layout with headers and buttons => clicking button will render datatable inside

```
 div id="@Model.ContainerSafeName-activitytable"
```

Below are relevant bits:

Main layout:

```
 @model Models.Model
 @using Helpers;
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/PartialPrint.cshtml";
}

<div class="card card-block">
<div class='container'>

    <div class="card row">
        <div class="card-header text-center text-white" role="tab" id="Heading">
            <h5>Activities</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button role="button"
                    data-type="Activity"
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-sm-12 col-md-12"
                    data-filters='@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.filters))'
                    data-url="@Url.Action("Activity_Page_activity", "Activity", new { Area = "Activity" })"
                    data-containername="@Model.ContainerSafeName-activitytable"
                    id="btnReport_activity">
                Show Data
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="@Model.ContainerSafeName-activitytable">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript bit:

```
$('#btnReport_activity').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var filters = $(this).data('filters');
    //var filtersstring = JSON.stringify(filters)
    var containername = $(this).data('containername');
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: filters,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET'
    })
        .done(function (result) {
            alert("good");
            $("#" + containername).html(result);
            $(this).toggle();
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        });
});
```

Ajax fails with Invalid character error. Filters are just a list of values passed to mainLayout from controller. I suspect it returns something bad.

Can anyone please point me where it possibly could go wrong? Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

PS: I'm not posting it on a whim, I have done a lot of research prior to that (including json.stringifying data, etc.), literally banging myself against the wall at this point.

Comment: What is the response? Is it valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not need a datatype being a JSON. I had to make corrections as below in order to get a proper response:

```
$('#btnReport_activity').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var filters = $(this).data('filters');
    //var filtersstring = JSON.stringify(filters)
    var containername = $(this).data('containername');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(filters),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST'
    })
        .done(function (result) {
            alert("good");
            $("#" + containername).html(result);
            $(this).toggle();
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        });
});
```